# Include snippet but indent headings

Tags: jekyll

**tl,dr: can I `{% include %}` a file and increment all the heading levels?**

If I have a file `chapter1.md`:

```
# chapter 1

blah blah

## subheading 1

blah blah
```

When I render it with Jekyll, I get 'Chapter 1' as an `h1` and 'subheading 1' as an `h2`, as planned.

Now I have a different page, `book.md`, and I want to include my Chapter 1 into it like so:

```
# Book

Here is my book.

{% capture inc %}{% include chapter1.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ inc | markdownify }}

{% comment %} ditto for remaining chapters {% endcomment %}
```

Where the (silly) `capture`/`endcapture` is the usual trick for including snippet that you need to be rendered with markdown (without plugins).

Here, "chapter 1" is an `h1` and "subheading 1" is an `h2` (again, as expected - following the original markdown file).

**My question is**: How can I cause all the headings in `chapter1.md` to be incremented by one level upon inclusion so that "chapter 1" becomes an `h2` and "subheading 1" becomes an `h3`?

This allows me to use my chapter snippet both as a standalone file and included into a master document.

Is there a `{{ inc | markdownify: 'header-increment', '1'}}` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I {% include %} a file and increment all the heading levels?

Not really. Neither Jekyll nor Liquid have a built-in way to indent header levels as described. You could ostensibly write a plugin to make the appropriate transformation, but it's a nontrivial task (that is to say, naively `gsub`ing `#` for `##`, for example, would break any use of "#" in code blocks or paragraphs).

It'd be much easier to simply maintain a convention that chapter content start at `h2`. Alternatively, you could nest chapters in an `article` or `section` tag, and differentiate using CSS without running afoul of markup semantics.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of nesting the included documents in tags and using CSS to demote the headings (stylistically anyway). In the long run I might look at using pandoc as my converter as writing such a plugin would be trivial in pandoc. I just haven't yet because I'm trying to use github-pages which has the no-plugin restriction (though eventually I'm sure I will end up doing what everyone else does and compiling the site to publish on gh)